# UITableView is not scrolling at all

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, scroll

I need to display a list of items in the `UITableView` and it should become visible when the user clicks on the button. It should be something like an alert box with a tableView.

So I created a `UIView`and inside it I've put my `UITableView` and then I've successfully created a custom alert box kind of thing.

But the issue is that the `UITableView` is not scrollable. It is just displaying as many items as its `UIView` parent size is.

How can i make an `UITableView` scroll that has been placed inside a `UITableView`?

I am using Swift4 and Xcode9 and recently started learning iOS development.

[image: storyboard][image: tableview in portrait orientation][image: landscape orientation]

Comment: Calculate the height of your `UITableView` and the parent `UIView`. If your `tableView`'s height is greater than your parent view then it won't scroll. Check that.

Comment: I checked and the height of UIView is 440.666 and the height of UITableView is 396.666.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: hey peter, i have added the screenshots of simulator with my storyboard where you can see all the constraints

Comment: Are you getting any bouncing effect or nothing at all?

Comment: Nothing.. tableView is stuck to its parent view. No effect at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165414/discussion-between-ipeter-and-sohaib-karim).